# В какой файл засунуть xrandr?

Tags: linux, debian, unix, администрирование, astra-linux

Настраиваю два экрана, сейчас дублируются, хочу чтобы один был правее другого

xrandr --output VGA1 --right-of HDMI1

в этом случае все превращаестя а один рабочий стол, как и надо!

Вопрос в том куда эту команду засунуть, чтобы при старте системы(графики) команда исполнялась?

в .profile и .bashrc не прокатывает.

OS Astra Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

начните проверки с `~/.xsessionrc`

если не поможет, проанализируйте содержимое файла `/etc/X11/Xsession` (и вызываемых из него других конфигурационных скриптов).

Answer (score 0):

в файл .profile, после команды надо дописать символ амперсанда &:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --right-of HDMI1 &
```

Comment: К сожалению, не сработало