# Запуск скрипта со стартом системы

Tags: bash, archlinux

Есть скрипт `~/.update` (исполняемый) с содержимым:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo pacman -Syu && yaourt -Syua
```

Скрипт добавлен в автозапуск, но при старте системы терминал не запускается, следовательно скрипт не выполняется. Но при ручном запуске скрипта он работает.

Что нужно подправить, чтобы этот скрипт выполнялся при загрузке ос (Arch linux, De Cinnamon)? То есть, чтобы запускался эмулятор терминала, и выполнялся скрипт.

Comment: Если программе нужен настоящий терминал, а проблема не в чем то ином (например в том, что в скриптах запуска в переменной PATH очень мало директорий и нужные вам команды могут просто не находится и надо писать полные пути), то вам надо воспользоваться утилитой `screen` http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+screen

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что мне нужен screen. этот скрипт должен выполняться уже после загрузки DE , стартанули иксы, после открылся эмулятор терменала допустим тот же xterm , а в нем выполнился этот скрипт, после чего эмулятор терминала закрылся

Comment: Вы бы в вопросе тогда и указали, что имеете ввиду X-овый терминал и что программам для работы нужны X-ы. В общем вам надо добавлять их тогда в скрипты запускаемые при загрузке X-ов, а не в скрипты запуска системы (какие конкретно, не помню, c X-ми не дружу). И заодно в вопросе обозначили что такое "добавлен в автозапуск", автозапуски разные бывают

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что скрипт не выполняется? Добавьте в скрипт строчку `echo "helloworld" > ~/update.log`, перезагрузитесь и проверьте, создаётся ли файл.

Answer (score 1):

если нужно, чтобы скрипт запустился в эмуляторе терминала (например, *xterm*), то и надо вызывать эмулятор.

т.е., вместо `~/.update` надо выполнять что-нибудь вроде:

```
xterm -e "~/.update"
```

---

выполняться эта команда должна, естественно, в каком-то из запускаемых при старте x-сессии скриптов. например, [`~/.xsessionrc`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608026/178576).

---

но, подозреваю, что это не всё: после завершения команд окно эмулятора закроется. чтобы оно не закрылось, а ожидало нажатия <kbd>enter</kbd>, можно добавить в конец команды вызов встроенной в оболочку команды *read*:

```
xterm -e "~/.update; read"
```